# Loop through range, if match copy specific cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have this formula that is working, it looks into a value and if there is a match between the sheets then it prints out what row the match is in. But what I would like it to do is that If match if found then copy value from column B in the same row as the value is found.

So if match is found between A2 in sheet1 and range A:A in sheet2, and lets say the row is 5, I want it to copy B5. Is this possible?

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A1;Indata!A:A;0));"";  MATCH(A1;Sheet2!A:A;0))
```

Comment: There is... give me a minute

Answer (score 1):

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A1,Sheet2!A:A,0)),"",INDEX(Sheet2!B:B,MATCH(A1,Sheet2!A:A,0)))
```

Comment: FWIW: If IFERROR is available, I believe it came out with excel 2007 then the formula above can be shortened to `=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!B:B;MATCH(A1;Sheet2!A:A;0));"")`